# Importing a .csv containing list of complex numbers

Tags: import, list-manipulation, version-12.2

I exported a list (with two columns) to a .csv file with Mathematica, and the first few lines are,

```
-3.141592653589793,-942.4277659056601-7.514067804073956*^-12*I
-3.141592653589793,155.66354907107547-5.760593016133258*^-13*I
-3.141592653589793,-101.00525445626336-1.443383665316593*^-14*I
```

To export, I used the command

```
Export["table.csv", a]
```

When I import this table, Mathematica cannot interpret the complex numbers in the second column properly. How do I properly import this csv file into a table?

```
In[1]:= a = Import["table.csv"];

In[2]:= a[[1]]

Out[2]= {-3.14159, "-942.4277659056601-7.514067804073956*^-12*I"}

In[3]:= Re[a[[1]]]

Out[3]= {-3.14159, Re["-942.4277659056601-7.514067804073956*^-12*I"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should interpret the complex number strings:

```
blist = ToExpression[#] & /@ a
```

> ```
> {{-3.14159, -942.428 - 7.51407*10^-12 I}, {-3.14159, 
>   155.664 - 5.76059*10^-13 I}, {-3.14159, -101.005 - 
>    1.44338*10^-14 I}}
> ```

Comment: It works. Could you explain the meaning of the syntax `ToExpression[#] & /@`?

Comment: `ToExpression[#]&`  is a pure function with one slot called `#`. This is where the input goes. The `&` is the end of the function. The `/@` is `Map`ping this function to each item in the list `a`. In plain English: Convert the string encountered to an Mma expression as you walk down the list `a`. If a list is encountered it changes its elements to expressions.

Comment: @Syed Why not `ToExpression /@ a`?

Comment: @MarcoB The shortened form is indeed better. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.